# How do i export c++ method symbol and exec from shell？

Tags: c++

i understand by using `extern "C"`, i can call c++ method from a c program because different name mangling strategy.

Now i want to call a c++ method from shell, but i don't know how?

For example, i have some code like below:

```cpp
extern "C" void Print_Statistic(){
    // output some data to console
}

int main() {
    // something works
    return 0;
}
```

And while the program is running, i'd like to attach to its process and call `Print_Statistic()` from shell command line, so i can get some data printed at console.
i really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Shells don't work that way, they can only execute programs (which invokes the `main` function).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Shells **can** send signals to running programs. The KILL signal is common, but HUP is often used to tell a running program that it needs to reload config.

Comment: I see two options: 1. read commands from standard input (i.e. `std::cin`). Then, your shell could pipe commands into it. 2. provide your program command line arguments to enable/disable options for its execution. ([LeanCpp.com: Command line arguments](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/command-line-arguments/))

Comment: @MSalters But it's still not the same as "calling" an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a POSIXy shell, you would need to call `void Print_Statistic()` from a `signal` handler. Then, you **set a reminder flag** to print those statistics. Inside the signal handler, you can't print. The signal has no idea if the targte program might be printing anything at the same time!

How you'd check that reminder flag from your other code is up to you; that's a higher-level design question.

Answer (score 0):

When you wish to trigger a `print_statistics()` from the command-line, you need an additional program that performs the trigger. This trigger must behave in an inter-process way; your additional program is one process and your original program is the other process. Besides `std::filesystem`, standard C++ provides no inter-process communication, and unfortunately for you, `std::filesystem` is not very suitable for your purpose. So then you need an operating system dependent solution, and preferably a solution that operates rather similar for different operating systems. Below I've included some code that is intended for both linux and Windows.

Your original program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __linux__ 

#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using event_t = sem_t*;

event_t create_event()
{
    event_t event = sem_open("/print_statistics", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
    if (event == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        int error = errno;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "sem_open failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    return event;
}

bool wait_for(event_t& event)
{
    if (sem_wait(event))
    {
        int error = errno;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "sem_wait failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    return true;
}

void close_event(event_t& event) noexcept
{
    sem_close(event);
}

#elif _WIN32

#include <Windows.h>

using event_t = HANDLE;

event_t create_event()
{
    event_t event = CreateEventA(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, "Local\\print_statistics");
    if (!event)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "CreateEventA failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    return event;
}

bool wait_for(event_t& event)
{
    if( WaitForSingleObject( event, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "WaitForSingleObject failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    return true;
}

void close_event(event_t& event) noexcept
{
    CloseHandle(event);
}

#else
# error "Unsupported OS"
#endif

void print_statistics()
{
    std::cout << "some data" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    try
    {
        auto close_on_exit = [](event_t* p) { close_event(*p); };
        event_t event = create_event();
        std::unique_ptr<event_t, decltype(close_on_exit)> raii_event(&event, close_on_exit);

        std::atomic_bool do_continue = true;
        std::future<void> print_statistic_future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&do_continue, &event]()
            {
                auto make_false_on_exit = [](std::atomic_bool* p) { *p = false; };
                std::unique_ptr<std::atomic_bool, decltype(make_false_on_exit)> raii_do_continue(&do_continue, make_false_on_exit);
                while (wait_for(event))
                {
                    print_statistics();
                }
            });
        while (do_continue)
        {
            // something works
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
        print_statistic_future.get();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The additional program to give the trigger:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __linux__ 

#include <semaphore.h>

void trigger_event()
{
    sem_t* event = sem_open("/print_statistics", 0);
    if (event == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        int error = errno;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "sem_open failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    if (sem_post(event))
    {
        int error = errno;
        sem_close(event);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "sem_post failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    sem_close(event);
}

#elif _WIN32

#include <Windows.h>

void trigger_event()
{
    HANDLE event = OpenEventA(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, "Local\\print_statistics");
    if (!event)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "OpenEventA failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    if (!SetEvent(event))
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(event);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "SetEvent failed with error code " << error << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
    CloseHandle(event);
}

#else
# error "Unsupported OS"
#endif

int main()
{
    try
    {
        trigger_event();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The additional program is not so hard to read, I guess.

Your original program became quite more complex.
To print the statistics, a future was created. This future is hanging in the `wait_for(event)` call until the additional program provided the trigger. Error handling, setting the `do_continue` boolean to false, and closing the event further complicates code. Please note that when `print_statistics` reads data which is also written in the `// something works` code, that then this data is to be protected by e.g. a mutex.